# How to avoid having too many nested function when using promises

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I'm working on a Discord bot using Discord.js. Here's the code I want to simplify:

```js
message.channel.send('**Card 1:** (type `next` to reveal the second card) \n' + specs[Math.floor(Math.random() * specs.length)][pictureKey]).then(() => {
  message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
      max: 1,
      time: 30000,
      errors: ['time']
    })
    .then(collected => {
      message.channel.send('**Card 2:** (type `next` to reveal the third card) \n' + specs[Math.floor(Math.random() * specs.length)][pictureKey]).then(() => {
        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
            max: 1,
            time: 30000,
            errors: ['time']
          })
          .then(collected => {
            message.channel.send('**Card 3:** (type `next` to reveal the fourth card) \n' + specs[Math.floor(Math.random() * specs.length)][pictureKey]).then(() => {
              message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                  max: 1,
                  time: 30000,
                  errors: ['time']
                })
                .then(collected => {
                  message.channel.send('**Card 4:** (type `next` to reveal the last card) \n' + specs[Math.floor(Math.random() * specs.length)][pictureKey]).then(() => {
                    message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
                        max: 1,
                        time: 30000,
                        errors: ['time']
                      })
                      .then(collected => {
                        message.channel.send('**Card 5:** \n' + specs[Math.floor(Math.random() * specs.length)][pictureKey]);
                      })
                  })
                })
            })
          })
      })
    })
    .catch(collected => {
      message.channel.send('Pack forfeited.');
    });
});
```

The code above works, but it's too messy. Is there a way to simplify this?

EDIT:

```js
async function revealCard(i) {
  message.channel.send(`**Card ${i + 1}:** (type \`next\` to reveal card ${i + 2}) \n` + specs[Math.floor(Math.random() * specs.length)][pictureKey]);
  let collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
    max: 1,
    time: 30000,
    errors: ['time']
  });
}

for (i = 0; i > 5; i++) {
  revealCard(i);

  if (collected === null) {
    break;
  }
}
```

This is my current code. Pretty sure I must have done something wrong because when I attempt running this command, nothing happens. No errors. Just nothingness. Am I doing this correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use async / await syntax: https://blog.logrocket.com/promise-chaining-is-dead-long-live-async-await-445897870abc/

Comment: Well, first of all: have you put that code in the part where the command code goes? Also, by moving the loop outside of the async function you end up with the same problem, adding the fact you're not waiting for the collector to finish when your run the next function, and you check for a `collected` variable that's not declared in the same scope. You should put *everything* that you want the program to wait for in the async function.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but it seems like you should take some time to review the basics of JS and Promises before moving to this kind of stuff: I'm just telling you because I think you would have a way easier time by reviewing those topics, instead of having to learn it "the hard way". There are a lot of great resources for that: MDN, FreeCodeCamp, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Other's have mentioned using await, but another solution is just to return the promise instead.

For example:

```js
client.channels.fetch("id")
 .then(channel => channel.messages.fetch("id"))
 .then(message => message.delete())
 .then(() => console.log("done"));
```

Like Federico Grandi suggested I think you should relearn the basics instead of just using a library like discord.js,
99% of the errors you will come across is just because you don't know js, like most of the posts on here.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in one of the comments, you should try using [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await): every time you have a `.then()` you can replace it like with an `await` keyword, provided that you're using an `async` function.
Here's how I would do it:

```js
// It's important that you're inside an async function (it will return a Promise)
async function yourStuff() {
  // Every time you want to wait for a Promise to resolve, use the await keyword
  await message.channel.send('**Card 1:** (type `next` to reveal the second card) \n' + specs[Math.floor(Math.random() * specs.length)][pictureKey])
  await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
    max: 1,
    time: 30000,
    errors: ['time']
  })

  await message.channel.send('**Card 2:** (type `next` to reveal the third card) \n' + specs[Math.floor(Math.random() * specs.length)][pictureKey])
  await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
    max: 1,
    time: 30000,
    errors: ['time']
  })

  // And so on...

  // If you want to get the result of the Promise you can store it in a variable like this:
  let collected = await message.channel.awaitMessage(...)
}
```

Comment: hey, i have posted my updated code in the answers section, could you please help me out?